# Porting from itextsharp to itext 7 - Why is itext7 giving me a slightly larger value for the Height of text for the same PDF?

Tags: .net, itext, itext7

I am in the process of porting my code to itext 7. While running some unit tests, I noticed that there was a difference of about 2 pixels or more in the height of text elements when I compared the same PDF with itextsharp and itext7.
[image]

The difference becomes progressively higher with increasing text size. I have a custom strategy class with the following code snippet. The variables **width** and **height** shows how I am arriving at the dimensions.

```
public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
        var baseline = renderInfo.GetBaseline();
        var ptStartBaseline = baseline.GetStartPoint();
        var ptEndBaseline = baseline.GetEndPoint();

        var bottomLeft = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
        var topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

        float xbotleft = bottomLeft.Get(iText.Kernel.Geom.Vector.I1);
        float ybotleft = bottomLeft.Get(iText.Kernel.Geom.Vector.I2);
        float xtopright = topRight.Get(iText.Kernel.Geom.Vector.I1);
        float ytopright = topRight.Get(iText.Kernel.Geom.Vector.I2);

        float width =   xtopright - xbotleft;
        float height =  ytopright - ybotleft;

}
```

Where am I going wrong? 
Thanks,
Sau

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Shared through Google Drive.  [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_RoIBA2XSXTUMFO-a9Hjwrn2QNJRL4U1?usp=sharing)

Comment: I look at this later, No time yet.